# Substring in SQL with from a pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, substring, patindex

I am struggling to substring and get the values in SQL.

I am having a JSON String like the following:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max)= '[{"CustomFieldId":18,"FieldName":"ABCD","FieldType":"freeText","FieldValue":null,"Details":null,"Value":null,"RelationTable":null,"Isisible":true,"IsAdmin":false,"CreatedDate":null,"ModifiedDate":null,"LoggedInUser":"TESTUSER"},{"CustomFieldId":19,"FieldName":"Workdomain","FieldType":"freeText","FieldValue":null,"Details":null,"Value":null,"RelationTable":null,"IsVisible":true,"IsAdmin":false,"CreatedDate":null,"ModifiedDate":null,"LoggedInUser":"149645"},{"CustomFieldId":20,"FieldName":"TEST1234","FieldType":"freeText","FieldValue":"Sometest","Details":null,"Value":null,"RelationTable":null,"IsVisible":false,"IsAdmin":false,"CreatedDate":null,"ModifiedDate":null,"_listlovFields":[],"org4Values":[],"LoggedInUser":"TESTUSER"}]'
```

or it can also be like this:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max) = '[{"CustomFieldId":20,"FieldName":"TEST1234","FieldType":"freeText","FieldValue":"Sometest","Details":null,"Value":null,"RelationTable":null,"IsVisible":false,"IsAdmin":false,"CreatedDate":null,"ModifiedDate":null,"LoggedInUser":"TESTUSER"}]'
```

Now from any one of them I need to get the 'FieldValue' of a particular 'CustomFieldId' with a particular 'FieldName' and where the FieldValue starts with a particular string.

Like, I am going to get these:

```
declare @propName varchar(max) = 'Test1234',
@customFieldId varchar(max) = 20,
@value varchar(max) = 'Some'
```

So, in this particular case, I need to get the FieldValue of customfield with CustomFieldId:"20", FieldName":"TEST1234" and where FieldValue starts with 'Some'.

The output simply needs be the string 'Sometest' as this is the FieldValue of CustomFieldId:"20"

Any help in this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Am not clear with your expected result. Can you put that in table format

Comment: The output simply needs be the string 'Sometest' as this is the FieldValue of CustomFieldId:"20". I would not be able to put that in a table format as I am only dealing with JSON strings stored in a table column.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite easy to solve when you install regex functions on your sql server. I've included the link where you can find them.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

```
declare @CustomFieldId nvarchar(50)= '20'
declare @FieldName nvarchar(50) = 'TEST1234'
declare @FieldValueStartsWith nvarchar(50) = 'Some'

declare @input nvarchar(500)
select @input = '[{"CustomFieldId":20,"FieldName":"TEST1234","FieldType":"freeText","FieldValue":"Sometest","Details":null,"Value":null,"RelationTable":null,"IsVisible":false,"IsAdmin":false,"CreatedDate":null,"ModifiedDate":null,"LoggedInUser":"TESTUSER"}]'

declare @result nvarchar(500)
declare @expression nvarchar(200) = '.*"CustomFieldId":' + @CustomFieldId + ',"FieldName":"' + @FieldName + '".*"FieldValue":("' + @FieldValueStartsWith + '\w+").*'
select @result = dbo.RegExReplaceX(@expression,@input,'$1',dbo.RegExOptionEnumeration(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0)) -- OPTION = FOR CASE SENSITIVE 
if @result = @input SELECT NULL ELSE SELECT @RESULT
```